# How to extract an specific portion of data( a block) from text

Tags: julia

I have a big text file including several blocks of data in which blocks are separated by {}. I need two portion of data from the file to work with.

I tried to find the title of target data(e.g. "job") in order to read following lines until next }, that I failed in the first step:

```
open("file.txt","r") do f
    for j in eachline(f) 
    if "job" in j
        return true
        return false
    end
end
end
```

So I am looking forward to any help.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a running example with the expected output, so that answers are focused on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one possibility using a single loop:

```
open("file.txt") do f
    job_found = false
    while true
        line = readline(f)
        if job_found
            occursin("}", line) && break
            println(line)
        else
            job_found = occursin("job", line)
        end 
    end
end
```

This code will print all lines after `"job"` string is contained in `line` until `"}"` is contained in some `line`.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked. What if I want to find the next block of data that is starting by the same title "Job"?

Comment: Change `while true` to `while !eof(f)` and `occursin("}", line) && break; println(line)` to `occursin("}", line) ? (job_found = false) : println(line)`. In this way you will get printed all lines between "job" and "}" for all repeating blocks.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following command to do it :

## sed

## awk

but it's better to send your text to check it better or take the sample of this

Comment: it seems some part of your comment is missing

Answer (score 0):

By using the awk or sed commands with their switches , you can see the better result , because i have not example of your text to help better